Stacked and column bar chart
I am trying to make a column chart where in if the values in the category are positive and negative, they are going to be in one column but if the values in the category are both positive or both negatives then they must be displayed side by side instead.
Currently it looks like this as a stacked bar chart. But looks incorrect when both values in same category are positive/negative as it must be side by side.

One possible solution would be to split the chart in 2 layers.
Layer 1: Stacked bars. Filter on smallest value per year < 0
Make this as per today.
Layer 2: Unstacked bars. Filter on smallest value per year >= 0
Create a new layer for this.
Let us know how you get along. Marks as solved if this helps.

Thanks! I was able to make it work similar to the logic above by having two rect marks - simiilar to layer in Vega-Lite

Excellent news! Feel free to post your solution in your question above for the community to see.
